# jquery getting post action url

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to access the post target action in a jquery function.

example:

```
<form action="/page/users" id="signup" method="post">
```

I'd like to access the "action" part - "/page/users" in this case.

```
$('#signup').live("submit", function(event) {
    // get this submitted action
}
```

Seems like I'm missing something very simple. I see the value in the dom but don't know where it's stored in jquery.

Thanks!

Answer (score 131, accepted):

```
$('#signup').on("submit", function(event) {
    $form = $(this); //wrap this in jQuery

    alert('the action is: ' + $form.attr('action'));
});
```

Comment: isn't the second line unnecessary, couldnt the third line be like  alert('the action is: ' + $(this).attr('action'));

Comment: True @9kSoft, but we get the idea :)

Comment: FYI: `live()` was deprecated in 1.7 and removed in 1.9. Devs should now use `on()` instead.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work when a form has multiple submit buttons with different actions.

Comment: Sorry, but this will not work if you will be using formaction attribute https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_formaction.asp

Answer (score 18):

Try this ocde;;

```
var formAction = $("#signup").attr('action');
```

Answer (score 11):

Clean and Simple:

```
$('#signup').submit(function(event) {

      alert(this.action);
});
```

Comment: Don't rely on this attribute since it may return the list of subnodes having name `action`.

Comment: First,the only use of `action` attribute is inside a html `form` tag.Second, nested `form`s are not best practice or good idea to have an clean optimized `Html DOM`.