# Getting ActionName and ControllerName dynamically with JQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I used the below code to get json response from controller. I am thinking of implementing this as a common function to have this used in all the views. How to pass `url` parameter dynamically?

```
$.ajax({type: 'POST',
    url: '@Url.Action("ActionName","ControllerName")',
    data: JSON.stringify($("form").serializeArray()),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function(status){
     ....

    } 
});
```

I thought of getting the name after defining the form parameters with controller and action name, but I could not get those parameters with jquery.

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("ActionName","ControllerName",FormMethod.POST)
```

Update: The new answer posted here is another bit easy way.

Comment: why you need to do this kind of things when the MVC already supports Ajax posting using Ajax.BeginForm

Comment: `url: $('form').attr('action'),`

Comment: @FrebinFrancis, I checked SO site and many places this code is being used instead of `Ajax.BeginForm` and thought this would be the good approach

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the MVC controller name in Javascript function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20450401/get-the-mvc-controller-name-in-javascript-function)

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Thanks Let me check that. Got it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get any form action using this `$form.attr('action')` you can write it in your js file as:

```
$(this).attr('action')
```

Same as this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/2550646/20126

Comment: Hey am not getting values as `\` when I use this code